# Mongoose : update object in array (bulkwrite)

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

i'm trying to update a object in array.

My field wasn't an array before, i used to use this code to update my field :

```
exports.updateStock = (req, res, next) => {
  console.log(req.body.order.products);
  let myOperations = req.body.order.products.map((prod) => {
    return {
      updateOne: {
        filter: { _id: prod._id },
        update: { $inc: { stock: -prod.quantity, sold: +prod.quantity } },
      },
    };
  });
  Product.bulkWrite(myOperations, {}, (err, products) => {
    if (err) {
      console.log("im here", err);
      return res.status(400).json({
        error: "Bulk operation failed",
      });
    }
    next();
  });
};
```

field :

```
stock: [
      {
        size: {
          type: String,
          required: true,
        },
        stock: {
          type: Number,
          required: true,
        },
      },
    ],
```

any idea how i can update my stock.stock based on size?
the size is passed with product -> prod.size

Example :

```
in store i have  size : M | 100 stocks
                        L | 150 stocks
                        XS| 10  stocks
user : want to buy size M and quantity 2
so after the order i have to update Size m stocks
100-2 = 98 stocks remaing after order :
                        M | 98 stocks
                        L | 150 stocks
                        XS| 10  stocks
```

My entire product schema :

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const { ObjectId } = mongoose.Schema;

const productSchema = new mongoose.Schema(
  {
    name: {
      type: String,
      trim: true,
      required: true,
      maxlength: 32,
    },
    description: {
      type: String,
      trim: true,
      required: true,
      maxlength: 2000,
    },
    discountprice: {
      type: Number,
      maxlength: 32,
      trim: true,
    },
    price: {
      type: Number,
      required: true,
      maxlength: 32,
      trim: true,
    },
    category: [
      {
        type: ObjectId,
        ref: "Category",
        required: true,
      },
    ],
    subcategory: [
      {
        type: ObjectId,
        ref: "SubCategory",
        required: true,
      },
    ],
    stock: [
      {
        size: {
          type: String,
          required: true,
        },
        stock: {
          type: Number,
          required: true,
        },
      },
    ],
    sold: {
      type: Number,
      default: 0,
    },
    photo: [String],
  },
  { timestamps: true }
);

module.exports = mongoose.model("Product", productSchema);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [arrayfilters](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/positional-filtered/index.html) to update `stock` on the base of `size` in array `stock`,

```
updateOne: {
  filter: { _id: prod._id },
  update: { $inc: { "stock.$[elem].stock": -prod.quantity, sold: +prod.quantity } },
  arrayFilters: [{ "elem.size": prod.size }]
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer , i'm little confused , how it knows for example that i want to update stocks of size M?

Comment: I am also confused your statement *any idea how i can update my stock.stock ?* you wanted to update stock property inside stock right? in your update query there is a field `sold` i can not see in your fields structure. so can you clear the things.

Comment: i am little confused can you give one example, when stock is 100 and size is M, and what and how you want to update it? do you want to update only M size stock only?

Comment: let's say you want to buy a t-shirt. you select size M and quantity 2 ... now i have to update Size M stocks ... so 100-2 = 98 remaining stocks.

Comment: every size has its own stocks

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/220047/discussion-between-im-ox-and-turivishal).